# NoSQL: How to retrieve a 'house' based on lat & long?

Tags: sql, database, rdbms, nosql, cassandra

I have a NoSQL system for storing real estate houses.

One piece of information I have in my key-value store for each house is the `longitude` and `latitude`.

If I wanted to retrieve all houses within a geo-lat/long box, like the SQL below:

```
SELECT * from houses 
WHERE latitude IS BETWEEN xxx AND yyy
AND longitude IS BETWEEN www AND zzz
```

Question:

1. How would I do this type of retrieval with NoSQL ... using just a key-value store system?
2. Even if I could do this with NoSQL, would it even be efficient or would simply going back to using a tradition database retrieve this type of information faster?

Comment: Depends on if your NoSQL database has spatial indexing.  If it does, then no problem, otherwise you're probably best to use a spatially-enabled SQL database for this... but the point is the index, not SQL.  Why not put just that information into PostGIS, and leave the rest in your NoSQL solution?

Comment: Not to be rude, but I'm specifically asking how to do this with NoSQL ... not PostGIS (with is a database)

Comment: MongoDB supports geo indexing: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing

Answer (score 2):

Sql or no sql is not the problem -- the problem is, strictly, what kind of indices do you have on your key.  [spatial indices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_index), which is what you'd need to satisfy your query efficiently, have nothing to do with Sql, or even more generally with relational databases -- they're totally orthogonal to relational vs non-relational issues.  Unfortunately, I don't know of any publicly available spatial-indexing systems for Cassandra or other popular non-relational DBs (indeed, the only GIS-oriented DB engine I know well is PostGIS, which happens to be built as an extension of the powerful open-source PostGres... which *is* relational;-).

If you don't have a spatial index but only a plain one (e.g., one sorted by Lat, then Long), then you'll have to scan through all records with suitable Lat, to discard those with unsuitable Long -- just as a relational engine would have to do for you under the same circumstances (when you select with a couple of `BETWEEN`s and all it has to go on is a plain sorted index of the two fields thus constrained).  Nothing to do with relational-ness... everything to do with indexing;-).

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB is the only NoSQL database I know of that supports geospatial indexes.  If you're using MongoDB, you should look at [the documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing), but basically you'd create a geospatial index with:

```
db.houses.ensureIndex({house : "2d"})
```

You'd insert points like:

```
db.houses.insert({house : {latitude : y, longitude : x}})
```

and then query for it with:

```
db.houses.find({house : {$within : {$box : [[xxx, yyy], [www, zzz]]}}})
```

MongoDB also lets you search within a given radius and just for the nearest matches to a point.

Answer (score 0):

Lucene also has something called Local Lucene. It can be reached over REST HTTP with Local Solr : http://www.gissearch.com/geo_search_intro http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch